# BCrypt Salt: Invalid Salt Length

Tags: java, php, android, bcrypt

Slowly progressing with my adventure into the land of security and I've hit yet another roadblock which i can't quite get my head around. Basically I'm trying to make my login system on my Android App as secure as possible. I intend to go SSL as soon as possible, but I want to cover all scenarios (such as cookie hijacking) therefore I don't want the user to send a password in plain text. I know SSL will take care of this, but why not lock your front door AND keep your passports in a safe.

Anyway, what I am doing is storing a unique salt for each user in the SQL database, retrieving this upon a login attempt, hashing the user password with this salt and cross checking on the server.

The issue I am having is that my unique salt is being created in PHP using the code

```
$salt = base64_encode(mcrypt_create_iv(16, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM));
```

I then append the "$2a$10$" and reduce the length of the $salt to 22 characters to match the BCrypt.gensalt() outputs. For example, the two salt calculations can return

```
$salt            = $2a$10$TGnr99x6uS2TexsSl0Xw==
BCrypt.gensalt() = $2a$10$hGSvqpfbuG4Y7JbSTZaV..
```

When I use hashpw with gensalt(), the hash works fine. However, when I use my unique salt, I get an error thrown for invalid salt length:

```
10-04 22:25:41.262    9093-9093/com.example.version02 E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.version02, PID: 9093
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Bad salt length
        at org.mindrot.jbcrypt.BCrypt.crypt_raw(BCrypt.java:622)
        at org.mindrot.jbcrypt.BCrypt.hashpw(BCrypt.java:692)
        at com.example.version02.Login$1.onClick(Login.java:90)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5156)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20755)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5832)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

Can anyone see what I'm doign wrong? Is it something simple that I'm going to end up poking myself in the eye for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it, after stumbling across a very apt site #9 http://blog.ircmaxell.com/2012/12/seven-ways-to-screw-up-bcrypt.html) I discovered that my salt was not being encoded correctly and I used their suggested method of `$userSalt = substr(strtr(base64_encode(mcrypt_create_iv(16, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM)), '+', '.'), 0, 22);` which works great with BCrypt `haspw`. Thanks for anyone who took the time to check on this for me and apologies for wasting anyone's time.

Comment: no, not interested in earning badges. Edited code but I also need 6 characters to change so that is the reason of artificial wasn't -> was not